# Sending a test email to myself (MailChimp), confusde by the weird HTML

Tags: html, email, html-email

So I'm sending a test email to myself, and when I view source, I see this:

```
<style type=3D"text/css">
=09=09body=2C#bodyTable=2C#bodyCell{
=09=09=09height:100% !important;
=09=09=09margin:0;
=09=09=09padding:0;
=09=09=09width:100% !important;
=09=09}
=09=09table{
=09=09=09border-collapse:collapse;
=09=09}
=09=09img=2Ca img{
=09=09=09border:0;
=09=09=09outline:none;
=09=09=09text-decoration:none;
```

I can view source in either GMail or on thunderbird, but it always has these special characters. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is encoded as [Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

It represents the data using 7-bits (rather than the more usual 8) and limits the line length for compatibility purposes.

Comment: I see. Any way to convert it back easily?

Comment: A [CPAN search](https://metacpan.org/search?q=quoted+printable) finds a [library that can do it](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::QuotedPrint). Replace CPAN with your library repository of choice for your language of choice, or search around for a prewritten utility program.